# Updates in 12.04 mess up nvidia drivers

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, updates

I am using the proprietary nVidia CUDA developer's drivers on my Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome 3 shell, from here:
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/drivers/devdriver_4.2_linux_64_295.41.run

Everything works well until I perform an update to the system (via the update manager).
Whenever something (I think xorg server) gets an update, the gnome shell boots only to 'Classic Mode'. Booting to recovery console and reinstalling the proprietary drivers solves the problem.

Is there any way to tell the update manager to *never* update/overrun the devdrivers?

It's really a pain having to reinstall the drivers every time I update the system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, really only every time you update the kernel, so either turn off kernel updates (purge the package linux-generic-pae) or add in your install script to /etc/kernel-img.conf which runs when the kernel updates.  Really though, how much trouble are you going to go to to avoud a "make install".